# callback in navigator.notification.confirm not working -- Phonegap_3.3.0-0.18.0

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins

I'm calling the navigator.notification.confirm where the call is made successfully and I'm able to see the confirm message box but the callback event is not getting fired on tapping exit button.

I'm using phonegap 3.3 on android.

Here is the code within in my index.html:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('DeviceReady'); 
    ref = window.open('http://www.rebonline.com.au/','_self','location=no,hidden=yes');
    checkConnection();      
}

function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
            var states = {};
            states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection!!!';
        if(Connection.NONE === networkState ){
           navigator.notification.confirm(states[networkState],function(button){
            if (button == 1) {
                if(navigator.app){
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }else if(navigator.device){
                    navigator.device.exitApp();
                }
            }
            }, 
            'Connection Status', 
            'Exit,OK'
            );
        }   
    }
```

What I need is to close my app when Exit button is tapped..

Answer (score 0):

Try using button value

```
 if (btn == 'yes') {
         navigator.app.exitApp(); // This is right syntax to close the app its working in my current app
                   }
              else {
                   //Continue
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not at my conputer for AFAIR the third parameter to the confirm should be and array, with the buttons strings inside.

.... [ "button1", "button2"]

Be sure to check the doc to confirm

Comment: Yes, it should be an array